# Codenameone : How to set MaxLines and MinLines in SpanLabel?

Tags: css, codenameone

`Label` in CN1 is limited to being a **Single line**.

Now that we have to use `SpanLabel` for **anything** that can take **more than 1 line**,

we face one issue.

When we have a strict design that uses consistent height for a list item, we have to give max/min lines allowed for the SpanLabel (At least that's how it works in Android And Flutter).

When I **searched** for anything that says ***line*** in `SpanLabel` file, I only found that word in one place, that too in a comment.

It **did not feel right** using **fixed** `height/width` property to a **SpanLabel** as they will vary with fonts and font sizes. The hight should be calculated with respect to the number of lines of the text & font config like **font size, line spacing, padding,** etc.

What is the right way to **achieve consistent height** across **various SpanLabel** despite the **varied length of the text** they display?

Answer (score 0):

The "right way" would be the layout manager as it would allocate the right amount of space to the span label and everything else. E.g. if you use `TableLayout` you can allocate the height as percentage.

`SpanLabel` is technically a `TextArea` that's encapsulated. It has that distinction between rows/lines which isn't exposed within `SpanLabel`. But you can manipulate the underlying text area by using `getTextComponent()`.